# Linear independence in P2 and P3

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vectors

If I have vectors that are linearly independent in P2 (vector space for polynomials degree 2) , does that mean they are linearly independent in P3 as well?

Comment: Yes. I think you need to state the linearly independent property, for both spaces and to see that there is no difference

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if two polynomials are linearly independent in $P_2$ they are also linearly independent in $P_3$

Adding $0x^3$ to both of them does not make one of them a scalar multiple of the other one if one is not already a scalar multiple of the other.